# Arquillian tool implementation for EJB unit testing

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss7.x, jboss-arquillian

I am working on a unit test implementation for an EJB module. I am using EJB 3, JBoss 7, Java EE 7 and JTA. I am using Arquillian for the EJB unit test.

I am facing some issues while configuring arquillian for the EJB unit test.

Here is my unit test code:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class TestCountryInfoControl {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = 
                Logger.getLogger(TestCountryInfoControl.class.getName());

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
                .addClasses(CountryInfoControl.class,
                            AddressParameterControl.class, 
                            AvStatusCodeControl.class)
                .addAsManifestResource("META-INF/persistence.xml", "persistence.xml")
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }

    @EJB
    private CountryInfoControl countryInfoControl;

    @Test
    public void callServiceToAddNewUserToDB() {
        String countryCode = "USA";
       System.out.println(countryCode);
    }
}
```

This is my POM.xml configuration

```xml
<!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
<!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
<!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss AS 7 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<profile>
    <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests
       in your JBoss AS instance -->
    <!-- This profile will start a new JBoss AS instance, and execute
       the test, shutting it down when done -->
    <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-jbossas-managed -->
    <id>arq-jbossas-managed</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>

<profile>
    <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests
       in a remote JBoss AS instance -->
    <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-jbossas-remote -->
    <id>arq-jbossas-remote</id>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>
```

And this is code in arqullian.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

   <!-- Uncomment to have test archives exported to the file system for inspection -->
<!--    <engine>  -->
<!--       <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/</property>  -->
<!--    </engine> -->

   <!-- Force the use of the Servlet 3.0 protocol with all containers,
        as it is the most mature -->
   <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />

   <!-- Example configuration for a remote JBoss AS 7 instance -->
   <container qualifier="jboss" default="true">
      <!-- If you want to use the JBOSS_HOME environment variable, 
           just delete the jbossHome property -->
      <!--<configuration>-->
         <!--<property name="jbossHome">/path/to/jboss/as</property>-->
      <!--</configuration>-->
   </container>

</arquillian>
```

I am getting the following exception when I am executing the test case:

```
    17:27:14,251 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014900: Content added at location D:\Dev\Project\GCS\Servers\jboss-eap-6.2.2\standalone\data\content\bf\fc95a3d63220d32769c1fd6b2018056be7e761\content
17:27:14,264 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "test.war" (runtime-name: "test.war")
17:27:14,701 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "test.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.3.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.3.2.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.pb.gpp.addressverification.ejb.controller.AddressParameterControl with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:72) [jboss-as-server-7.3.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.3.2.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:92)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.3.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.3.2.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/pb/gpp/commons/util/GPPException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2499) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1811) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.3.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.3.2.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:68) [jboss-as-server-7.3.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.3.2.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pb.gpp.commons.util.GPPException from [Module "deployment.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 15 more

17:27:14,708 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "test.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"test.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.pb.gpp.addressverification.ejb.controller.AddressParameterControl with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.test.war:main\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/pb/gpp/commons/util/GPPException
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pb.gpp.commons.util.GPPException from [Module \"deployment.test.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
17:27:14,736 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment test.war (runtime-name: test.war) in 28ms
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 11.405 sec <<< FAILURE!
com.pb.gpp.addressverification.ejb.controller.TestCountryInfoControl  Time elapsed: 11402 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Cannot deploy: test.war
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deployInternal(ArchiveDeployer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deployInternal(ArchiveDeployer.java:64)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deploy(ArchiveDeployer.java:46)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.deploy(CommonDeployableContainer.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:161)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:128)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:271)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deploy(ContainerDeployController.java:127)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createDeploymentContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.DeploymentExceptionHandler.verifyExpectedExceptionDuringDeploy(DeploymentExceptionHandler.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:80)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:263)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachManagedDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:239)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deployManaged(ContainerDeployController.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:182)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"test.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.pb.gpp.addressverification.ejb.controller.AddressParameterControl with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.test.war:main\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/pb/gpp/commons/util/GPPException
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pb.gpp.commons.util.GPPException from [Module \"deployment.test.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.getActionResult(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:134)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.getResultFromNode(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:123)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.get(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.get(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:42)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.ServerDeploymentHelper.deploy(ServerDeploymentHelper.java:52)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deployInternal(ArchiveDeployer.java:77)
    ... 96 more


Results :

Tests in error: 
  com.pb.gpp.addressverification.ejb.controller.TestCountryInfoControl: Cannot deploy: test.war

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you deploying a jar or a war?  --> Use `ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "test.jar")` or `ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")`

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be the type and name of your archive.  If you're trying to deploy a WAR file, you need to use a `WebArchive`, so change your deployment to look like

```
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
```

and this issue should go away.

Comment: I had updated code as suggested by you. Still I am getting exception. I had updated exception message also. I guess maybe I am not able to provide dependency to class path on test project. My ejb project have multiple classes including 3 ejb, few models and persistence class and ejb project and test project are in different namespaces. I am using maven for managing project dependency.

Comment: @Awadhendra you update the stracktrace right? Previously I saw that the problem is because you don't add the test class into the deployment archive. The test are running in a differente jvm, you have to provide access to all classes needed

Comment: Agreed.  The stacktrace is very clear on what's missing - `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pb.gpp.commons.util.GPPException from [Module "deployment.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader]` Most people find it easiest to build their archive (using maven), and then deploy that.